# css3 pointer-event NOT on child?

Tags: css

I have the folowwing structure

```
<div class='offline'>some text <button class='delete'>Delete</button></div>
```

Is it possible to disable the div with pointer-events: none  but KEEP the button active ?

I tried with

```
div.offline:not(.delete) {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

No success. Any idea ?

Comment: Your css is not targeting the child at the moment.

Comment: ok.. but can this be done ?

Comment: The question isn't clear.

Comment: yeah explain what do you want

Comment: So easy to test this yourself http://jsfiddle.net/vpawy34z/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable events on the parent and reenable them on the child.

```css
.parent {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.child {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  foo
  <button class='child'>bar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems not to work on mobile (or at least not on iOS)

Comment: @eds1999 I just tested iOS on both Safari & Chrome and this works, if you have an issue, it must lie somewhere else.

Comment: Hmm you're right. Safari seems to do exactly what you'd expect it to do. I was testing using Cordova and strangely enough the outcome is quite different there.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the `pointer-events: none;`:

> **none** 
> The element is never the target of mouse events; *however, mouse events may target its descendant elements if those descendants
> have pointer-events set to some other value.* In these circumstances,
> mouse events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
> appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
> capture/bubble phases.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Note the emphasis added above.

So basically descendants should still have those events if you set them:

```
.offline .delete {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this:

```
div.offline:not(.delete) {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

You are targeting `div`s with class `offline`, which don't have class `delete`.

Since your sole `div` doesn't have a `delete` class, it is targeted.

To target all descendant elements of `div.offline` that don't have the `delete` class, you would do this:

```
div.offline :not(.delete) {  //note the space before ":not"
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

However, that excludes text nodes.  So both "some text" and the `delete` button would still receive pointer events.

Your only option is to create a default style for the parent, which is overridden by the child:

```
div.offline {
  pointer-events: none;
}

div.offline .delete {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```